# Apex Test execution Queued

Tags: apex, class, unit-test

I am trying to run my apex test classes but it has been in queued status for very long time ( 3 hours). Initially I attempted to all test classes - after the while I aborted as it doesnt provided the test results. Then executed single test class still been in queued status for very long time.

I used to run all test class in this same org on alternative Monday - so far no such issues noticed. Any suggestion appreciated.

Already removed parallel execution in options and cleared all test results!!

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this myself from time to time. Try these things:

1. `Clear Test Data` from the Apex Test Results page.
2. Close and reopen the Developer Console, then explicitly select the class to test.
3. Use a different browser for the Developer Console - I had many issues with Firefox but the problems went away with Chrome